# $p(X)$, $P(Y)$, $p(Z) > 0$ and every pair of these events is independent, then $p(X \wedge Y \wedge Z) > 0$?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Is the following statement true or not?

> Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be $3$ events in the same sample space such that $p(X)$, $P(Y)$, $p(Z) > 0$ and every pair of these events is independent. Then $p(X \cap Y \cap Z) > 0$.

Answer (score 3):

No, the statement is not true. Let for example $Ω=\{1,2,3,4\}$ with $p(ω)=1/4$ for each $ω$ and let $X=\{1,2\},\, Y=\{2,3\}, \, Z=\{3,4\}$. Then $$P(X\cap Y\cap Z)=P(\emptyset)=0$$ but you can check that $X,Y,Z$ are pairwise independent with $P(X)=P(Y)=P(Z)=\frac12>0$.